Hibernate JPA gives Duplicate entry for PRIMARY KEY while saving new object after manual sql execution in db
I'm using JPA for mysql operations, but after some manual operations in the database (e.g. insert, delete, dump, etc..) when an entity is saved using Repository.save(entityModel). I get this error -
Duplicate entry 'x' for key 'xxxxx.PRIMARY'

My primary key's entity is this one
@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE )
protected Long id;


When you use sequence, you have to make sure everyone use the same sequence: even your script.

What happens with SEQUENCE is that it uses a database sequence which queries next sequence-id from db before insertion. Which in your case will be 1 behind the latest one in your actual data table as you have inserted manually. So you'll have to manually increase that sequence-id too. You can try looking for {yourTableName}_id_seq table in db.

The GenerationType.SEQUENCE maintains a table i.e. like entity_seq which has the column next_val from where it fetches the value for the next row insertion into the entity_table.

You have did manual insertion of data which means you have left the sequence table behind your entity table. You can simply modify the next_val from the sequence table to the (latest_id+1) of the original data table for solving this error.
